# How to fix the armadillo library to c++

Tags: c++, linker, armadillo

I'm using a macbook to program some bits of code here and there. Recently I wanted to do something in C++ together with the armadillo library. But after installation and everything it doesn't seem to work.

For instance I can write `arma::mat` variable, etc but when I run this code in TextMate:

```
vec q = randu<vec>(5); 
cout << normalise(q);
```

I get this error output:

```
"Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_wrapper_dgesdd_", referenced from:
      void arma::lapack::gesdd<double>(char*, int*, int*, double*, int*, double*, double*, int*, double*, int*, double*, int*, int*, int*) in test-56d704.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
rm: /var/folders/sh/vr2n15ln47j0k33yh1j0_tyw0000gn/T/test.cpp.Sfz5vezN: No such file or directory
```

The weird thing is that if I don't use the normalise or norm functions it compiles well.

I include the library as `#include '/usr/local/include/armadillo'`

Edit:
I've installed the armadillo package both trying with "`brew install armadillo`" but also with the steps mentioned in the README.txt if you download armadillo from their webpage.

Edit2:
In textmate i added a flag to variables in TM_CXX_FLAGS : -I /usr/local/include -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER -lblas -llapack .. this seems to solve the problem when compiling through textmate.. However I can't understand how to fix it in XCode

Edit3:
Found this as warnings when compiling...

clang: warning: -lblas: 'linker' input unused
clang: warning: -llapack: 'linker' input unused
clang: warning: -llapack: 'linker' input unused
clang: warning: -lblas: 'linker' input unused

Anyone know how to properly add flags for the compiler in Xcode?

Comment: 1) Have you checked path `/usr/local/include/armadillo`? May be you need to `#include "/usr/include/armadillo"`? 2) Are you sure, that you do not need to `#include "/usr/local/include/lapacke.h"`? (or similar path)

Comment: Did you forget to link with `-larmadillo` ?  For example: `g++ code.cpp -o code -O2 -larmadillo`

Comment: when i use the g++ thing i get the following error:

ld: library not found for -larmadillo
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

and when i try to use "/usr/local/include/lapacke.h" it says it doesn't find the file

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem first when I started to program with armadillo. For g++ I only had to add `-larmadillo` as command line option. such as this

```
g++ -O2 -o armadillo_example armadillo_example.cpp -larmadillo
```